Layout Paragraphs — How can I add styling options to regions?
I'm using Layout Paragraphs on a new site as a replacement for building out individual paragraphs that control layout (e.g. a paragraph called "2 Column Layout")
The design I'm working from will require regions of the site to have large background gradients or images applied. For instance, I might add a full width region to a page and then add 4 paragraph components to that region. That entire region will need to have a large background graphic that falls behind all 5 paragraphs.
Is it possible to add fields or options to layout regions to apply background color/image options? So far I'm coming up blank.

https://www.drupal.org/project/style_options might be an option.
